# auth on twitter for access to another site

Tags: java

I work on application, which try to get and parse information from site was named "Super-site" for instance. Access to data I needed is restricted and is necessary user authentication. I cannot ask user to send login\password from super-site, but Super-site have possibility authentication across social-auth (twitter). I can get access token from twitter, but I am unable to understand how to auth on Super-site using twitter access-token?

Comment: Does Twitter is mandatory ? Or another social service is possible ?

Comment: No, it can be something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will use the 3-legged OAuth with Twitter. [Here is the link from Twitter](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/oauth-1-0a/obtaining-user-access-tokens) that gives you steps. How you do this is by logging to your twitter account on developer.twitter.com, from Twitter Application Dashboard click on the Twitter App to create a Access Token and Access Token Secret. Your user accessing the Super-site will be prompted to authorize access to the Application, user grants access (clicks Yes) and finally your Super-site collects the OAuth token (user need not send username/password) and accesses the site.

Answer (score 1):

Your super site must use oauth flow.
Every api should have oauth  authentication and it is done at server end.

https://blog.restcase.com/4-most-used-rest-api-authentication-methods/

If they have twitter you can use twitter auth flow. They have to write code to understand twitter user account linking and authorization. So you login as a twitter user if thatuser is found in database  you receive token and you can call api based on twitter user authorization.
The previous versions of this spec, OAuth 1.0 and 1.0a, were much more complicated than OAuth 2.0. The biggest change in the latest version is that it’s no longer required to sign each call with a keyed hash. The most common implementations of OAuth use one or both of these tokens instead:

access token: sent like an API key, it allows the application to access a user’s data; optionally, access tokens can expire.
refresh token: optionally part of an OAuth flow, refresh tokens retrieve a new access token if they have expired. OAuth2 combines Authentication and Authorization to allow more sophisticated scope and validity control.
OAuth 2.0 is the best choice for identifying personal user accounts and granting proper permissions. In this method, the user logs into a system. That system will then request authentication, usually in the form of a token. The user will then forward this request to an authentication server, which will either reject or allow this authentication. From here, the token is provided to the user, and then to the requester. Such a token can then be checked at any time independently of the user by the requester for validation and can be used over time with strictly limited scope and age of validity.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/twitter-logins?view=aspnetcore-3.1